# Segmentation fault using static variable in Binary Tree

Tags: c++, recursion, static, binary-tree

Ques is **Given preorder and inorder traversal of a tree, construct the binary tree.** But I am getting this error:

> Runtime Error. Your submission stopped because of a runtime error. ex:
>   division by zero, array index out of bounds, uncaught exception You
>   can try testing your code with custom input and try putting debug
>   statements in your code. Segmentation fault

for the following code

```
int binary(int x , vector<int> &inorder , int lo , int hi){
    for(int i = lo ; i <= hi ; i++){
        if(inorder[i] == x){
            return i ;
        }
    }
    return -1 ;
}

TreeNode* rec(vector<int> &preorder, vector<int> &inorder, int a , int b){
    if(a > b)
        return NULL ;
    static int indx;
    int in = binary(preorder[indx], inorder, a , b) ;
    TreeNode *treenode = new TreeNode(preorder[indx]) ;
    (indx)++ ;
    treenode->left = rec(preorder, inorder, a, in-1) ;
    treenode->right = rec(preorder, inorder, in+1, b) ;
    return treenode ;
}

TreeNode* Solution::buildTree(vector<int> &preorder, vector<int> &inorder) {
    int sz = preorder.size() ;
    int index=0;
    return rec(preorder, inorder, 0, sz-1) ;
}
```

Comment: There can't be any good reason to use a static variable to implement a binary tree.

Comment: When I am passing the address of index and also doing the increment for inorder index then answer is right. But what is wrong using a static variable in this code??

Comment: If you use a static  variable, you can only have one tree instance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate that with the help of diagram or address in each call??
I would really help a lot.Thanks